# How to run code directly from python interpreter in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2, interpreter

I'm running a python script using Sublime Text 2. To run the script, I use command B--this works great until I want to explore some variable by typing it into the python interpreter, as the interpreter does not appear to be interactive. Is there any way to be able to input code into Sublime Text 2's interpreter in order to test ideas and code snippets before I add them to the main script?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think sublime support it. I know you can use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) when you need pass some users inputs.